# i am beginner in phonegap when i type cordova run android using CLI then does not any error or output

Tags: node.js, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap-desktop-app

i have install all prerequisite for cordova project in my system.
installed software like below.
1)node.js
2)cordova
3)phonegap
4)npm
5)jdk
6)jre
7)android - sdk

[error image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyjc8.png) error like in image.

when i have run 'cordova run android' in my project directory using CLI 
then error/output like in attached image.

i have already set path in environment variables.
please suggest some solution.

Comment: I don't see any error, it says "complete"

Comment: in my project apk file does not create when i have build project.

Answer (score 0):

This command is for running the app on an actual device. Have you set up the device and enabled USB debugging?

From [the docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/cli/index.html):

> Alternately, you can plug the handset into your computer and test the
>   app directly:
>
> ```
> $ cordova run android
> ```
>
> Before running this command, you need to set up the device for testing, following procedures that vary for each
>   platform. In Android and Amazon Fire OS devices, you would have to
>   enable a USB debugging option on the device, and perhaps add a USB
>   driver depending on your development environmnent. See Platform Guides
>   for details on each platform's requirements.

If you want to run the app in an emulator instead you should use:

```
$ cordova emulate android
```

Read all about it at: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/cli/index.html